# Force file download from HTTP on iOS

Tags: ios, macos, http, download, content-disposition

I am using a link to auto download file once clicked.
This download is working all fine in Android and Windows.

But on MAC and iOS the file is opening in browser only. It is not downloading.

I'm setting below response headers:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.csv"
```

I checked on SO and some suggested to use

```
Content-Type: application/force-download
```

But it is Hack, not a standard as per comments. So how can I achieve download in iOS and MAC?

Comment: This is not a Java/Servlet problem. iOS has a locked down file system so users are in first place already not able to browse file system for saved files. This needs to be "solved" in iOS side. See also a.o. http://ioshacker.com/cydia/safari-downloader-tweak-for-safari-iphone-ipad

Answer (score 2):

It's supported in iOS Safari from v13.1 onwards. See here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

In your content-type header you can *hack* it to work by setting the content type header in your server response

```
Content-Type: application/force-download
```