# Force download mime type if has a certain parameter in url

Tags: apache, mime-types

I know I can force download all files from specific folders or download all files with specified extensions. for example:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(mp3|avi)$" >
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header add Content-Disposition "attachment"
</FilesMatch>
```

But I want to force download a file if a parameter is given in request url, like `?download=true`. How can I do that?

Comment: make it nested `<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /download=true/"></If>`. One directive per line.

Comment: @Deadooshka I'm looking for the right if condition to nes it, actually!

Answer (score 0):

It is nice to be able to customize HTTP headers based on URL on a purely static website without any dynamic scripting language and their security issue.

## Sanity check applicability of headers

- Content-Disposition is described in [RFC6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266).
- Content-Type in HTTP context is described in [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7.2.1).

In theory only Content-Disposition "attachment" is necessary.

## Solution

Combining information in the question and first comment allows something that works for me: putting the lines below in a `.htaccess` at or above the directory containing files.

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /download=true/">
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header add Content-Disposition "attachment"
</If>
```

This is documented in [Expressions in Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html), does not appear to need any specific Apache module.

## Protocol-level test

### Before

```sh
curl -o /dev/null -v https://some.url/example.jpg 2>&1 | grep " Content"

< Content-Length: 1201533
< Content-Type: image/jpeg

curl -o /dev/null -v https://some.url/example.jpg?download=true 2>&1 | grep " Content"

< Content-Length: 1201533
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

### After

```sh
curl -o /dev/null -v https://some.url/example.jpg 2>&1 | grep " Content"

< Content-Length: 1201533
< Content-Type: image/jpeg

curl -o /dev/null -v https://some.url/example.jpg?download=true 2>&1 | grep " Content"

< Content-Length: 1201533
< Content-Disposition: attachment
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

### Practical test

- Desktop browsers: pass
- Android: pass
- iOS: file still shown instead of downloaded, but that's a different issue, see [macos - Force file download from HTTP on iOS - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886885/force-file-download-from-http-on-ios)

### Conclusion

Success!