# A Tag with download attribute not work in iphone?

Tags: html

I have to working for download video. I used the anchor tag and in which used download attribute. It would be working properly in all browser but in iphone, it directly plays that video.

Comment: Which iOS you are using, safari on iPhone/Ipad only support downloading file from iOS 13

Comment: I am tested in every iphone in safari and also in chrome

Comment: Hey @rohit were you able to find a fix to this? I tried using the header 'Content-type: application/force-download' but that just started showing the html page on phone. How to download video? I have exact same situation as yours. Video just plays with no option to download or save to gallery.

Answer (score 1):

It's supported in iOS Safari from v13.1 onwards. See here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

In your content type header you can *hack* it to work by setting the content type header in your server response

```
Content-Type: application/force-download
```

See this: [Force file download from HTTP on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886885/force-file-download-from-http-on-ios/58346019#58346019)