# download attribute of html is not working for iphone browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, download

I am trying to force download pdf instead of opening.
I have used

> `<a href='path' download>`

but its still open file in mobile devices like iphone
I need to force to download file instead of open
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297152/a-tag-with-download-attribute-not-work-in-iphone

Comment: Which PDF library is used in your project?

Comment: snappy pdf @MujahidBhoraniya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im giving you a idea for force downloading through php,

Create a PHP file download.php, change accordingly to your php app.

```
    <?php
// Ajmal Praveen
    $file_name = 'file.pdf';
    $file_url = 'http://yoururl.com/' . $file_name;
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
    readfile($file_url);
    exit;
    ?>
```

Make a link

```
<a href="./download.php?file=file.pdf" download>Download</a>
```